# Conky not autostarting on boot - Debian 8 (jessie)

Tags: linux, debian, conky

I can't get Conky to autostart on boot.

Heres the init-script I've got:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/autoconky

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          autoconky
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog $network $time
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog $network $time
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

# The following part carries out specific functions depending on arguments.

case "$1" in
  start)
    sleep 10
    conky -d -c ~/.conkyrc
    ;;
  stop)
    pkill conky
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/autoconky {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

I've added the scrit to autostart using: `update-rc.d autconky defaults` and the script do run on startup, but conky doesn't start.

By adding `mkdir ~/conkyTest` to the script (see example below) i could confirm that the script actually was running on startup, and it was.

```
...    
case "$1" in
  start)
    sleep 10
    mkdir ~/conkyTest
    conky -d -c ~/.conkyrc
    ;;
...
```

I can run `/etc/init.d/autoconky start` and it start without a problem.

I've tried different `sleep xx`, from 3 - 60 and I also tried `conky -p x` 3 - 60, all without any luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

If you’re under gnome, you can try this simple way [as explained here](http://www.planet-libre.org/?post_id=17158); works nice for me:

1. Create a file named `conky.desktop` in `/usr/share/gnome/autostart/`
2. Copy and add the lines you will find on the link.
3. `chmod 777 /usr/share/gnome/autostart/conky.desktop`
4. Maybe you will have to tweak the line that contain `Exec=conky -d` to fit your conky’s configuration.
5. Log out and log in again.